# ¿Como almacenar el rol del usuario del lado del cliente?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, jwt

[ utilizando react para el front  y la rest api la cree con node , express y la base de datos My Sql]

Estoy creando una aplicación y necesito almacenar el rol del usuario.

No se si alamacenarlo junto con el jwt en el localstorage o en una cookie o otro lugar, tengo poca experiencia en autentificación y toda la información que encontré es bastante ambigua.

Aparte quisiera saber si me recomiendan almacenar el JWT en el LocalStorage?
Y la pregunta main seria donde puedo almacenar el rol de usuario?

Comment: En jwt puedes almacenarlo en la *carga útil* en un *claim personalizado*, en [este ejemplo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Estructura) se usa `loggedInAs`. Para darte una respuesta concreta debes primero elegir alguna de las [implementaciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Implementaciones).

Answer (score 0):

Espero pueda serte de utilidad, aunque no creo que esta sea la mejor forma pero me ha funcionado. Una vez tienes el jwt token en el lado servidor puedes **enviarlo  al cliente** de la siguiente manera:

```
res.status(200).cookie('token', token).redirect('/ruta segura');
```

y luego, en la **ruta segura**, lado servidor:

```
app.get('/ruta segura', (req, res) => {
  let decoded = decodeToken(req);
  //hago cosas con el token
});

function decodeToken(req) {
    const tokenReq =
        req.headers.cookie["x-access-token"] ||
        req.headers.cookie ||
        req.headers["x-access-token"];
    let token = tokenReq.split("=").pop();
    const decoded = jwt.decode(token);
    return decoded;
}
```

saludos y espero pueda servirte!